# Weird spacing in Views content after unspecified module update

Tags: views

I'll preface this by saying, I am very new to Drupal and pretty much have no idea what I am doing.  I did not develop the site I am going to reference.  With that said, recently I updated a handful of modules, I couldn't say which ones (I can't remember) and now there is some weird spacing on one of our pages which was created with Views.

The page that is throwing a weird spacing issue is https://tarltontest.law.utexas.edu/about-the-library/hours

The issue is that the data range between parentheses is now on three lines, rather than inline with the title, ie Fall Semester Hours, Fall Finals Hours, etc.

I cannot figure out where the spacing is coming from.  I cannot see anything in the Views settings that would cause this.  IS this a template file>  CSS? I don't even know where the parentheses are coming from.

I would love any help in identifying where to possibly look to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

> The issue is that the data range between parentheses is now on three
>   lines, rather than inline with the title, ie Fall Semester Hours, Fall
>   Finals Hours, etc.

looks fine to me...